# Regular Expression: Split English and Non-English words with Comma?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Is there any regular expression pattern to change this string

> This is a mix string of üößñ and English. üößñ üößñ are Unicode words.

to this?

> This is a mix string of, üößñ, and English., üößñ üößñ, are Unicode words.

Actually, I want to split English words and non-English words with comma.

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? Regular expressions are not standardized between environments, and even those that claim to be "Perl-compatible" vary on some important points.

Comment: Define "non-english". Is "bonjour" English? How about näive or jalapeño?

Comment: I think he means all standard English characters (alpha numeric)i.e. A-Fa-f0-9

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves
Non-English == The words which contain the characters outside of the Unicode Range \u0000 to \u0080.

Thanks

Comment: @RageZ: Yes, your are right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript

/((?:\ [^\w\d]+)+)/g

'This is a mix string of üößñ and English. üößñ üößñ are Unicode words.'.replace(/((?:\ [^\w\d]+)+)/g,',$1,')

This is a mix string of, üößñ, and English., üößñ üößñ, are Unicode words.

Mark

Answer (score 1):

No regular expression can detect strings in a particular *language*, but you can certainly match characters in (or not in) a range of code points, by using unicode literals, such as

```
/[\u0900-\u097F]+/
```

which matches a sequence of Devanagari characters.

Remember that a Script (a collection of characters) can be used by many languages.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use \x to filter specific ASCII code ranges

For example (in JavaScript):

```
var x = "This is a mix string of üößñ and English. üößñ üößñ are Unicode characters.";
x.replace(/([^\x00-\x80]+\s)+/g, function(match) { return match.slice(0,-1)+", "; } ); // matches characters outside the 0-128 ASCII range
```

Output:

> This is a mix string of üößñ, and English. üößñ üößñ, are Unicode characters.

I'm sure another regex savvy person can optimize further, but this is the best I can think of half-awake :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "This is a mix string of üößñ and English. üößñ üößñ are Unicode words.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("((?: ?[\\p{L}&&[^A-Za-z]]+)+)", ",$1,"));
```

Unicode scripts define about [45 different language](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) scripts.  The above simply detects any unicode not in the ASCII range.